# Adding Le Pouce Grid coordinate system to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, pdf, mauritius

I regularly deal with CAD files in this legacy coordinate system and I wanted to include it in ArcMap.
I have the following data from the Control Network booklet from the Ministry of Housing and Lands but unlike a standard projected coordinate system, I do not know where to input these info.

[image]

Other information available in the booklet are highlighted in this table.

[image]

Comment: Definitely not it. While the scale factor is correct, CAD files do not align to orthophoto.

Comment: All the values you have in your grid (match those of [EPSG:3337](https://epsg.org/crs_3337/Le-Pouce-1934-Mauritius-Grid.html).  EPSG cites as its source `Cartographic Saection, Ministry of Housing and Lands.`  presumably an earlier version of  https://housing.govmu.org/Documents/Survey/Cadastre/Control%20Network%20Mauritius%202013.pdf  It's difficult to see how you could enter those values as a custom projection and get a different result than choosing EPSG:3337.

Comment: Yes, ArcMap has it. It was added in 9.3. Might be in Oceans or National Grids. You should be able to search on 3337. Make sure you open the transformations dialog and set the La Pouce to WGS 1984 1 transformation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood properly. Should I modify the Le Pouce Transformation by specifying somewhere the WGS 1984 detail?